# CakePHP same 'view' for multiple functions

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

I have a Cakephp project 
the controller has several different methods.

```
function Index()
function IndexAuthor()
```

And I want to use the same 'view' (or template, Index.ctp) for both of the methods of the control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`Controller::render()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render).

```
function IndexAuthor() {
    $this->render('index');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Form->checkbox('is_active', array('is_active', value = 'active')) . 'Active';
?>

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer + are you sure that's the right answer?